# Rings/Isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $\mathbb{R}^2$ be the set of pairs of real numbers and let $\mathbb{R}^2: (a,b) + (c,d) = (a+b, c+d)$. Find a binary operation * on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $(\mathbb{R}^2 , +, *)$ is a ring which is isomorphic to the complex numbers.

I know how to show that something is isomorphic, but I am confused how to find a binary operation that will satisfy the question. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Find the map that you want to be the isomorphism, then transport the complex multiplication to $\mathbb{R}^2$ via that.

Comment: are you sure about the addition ? or is it (a+c,b+d) ?

Comment: @dkuper: you are right, it can't be a ring with this addition anyway

Comment: Do you know how multiplication is defined for complex numbers, @kkkk ?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Define $\phi : \mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ by $\phi(a+ib) = (a,b)$. This is a bijection, and already a group homomorphism for the addition $(a,b) + (c,d) = (a+c, b+d)$. If you want it to be a ring homomorphism, what additional equation should $\phi$ satisfy?